# How to make the page width for text broader in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I need to have more space for text in my Google Docs, but under Format and Edit, I cannot find how to make the page width wider. Where are these page settings in Google Docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a wider paper side, you can change the page orientation or paper size to e.g. A3.

[image]

[image]

The `Pageless` modus seems is suitable for Large Images, but still limits the text width.

If you only want to view it you can of course also choose a smaller text font and zoom out by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd>

Comment: Line wraps cannot be read so easily if you have far too long lines like in A3 (meaning even in portrait mode), there is a reason why the standard for code is often just 79 characters. I just wanted to share where these page margins are since I had searched for them a couple of times to no avail. Your answer to use "pageless" is a good idea and I tested it on a large doc, it adds more scrollability and oversight and takes away the narrow-looking sides. In my case, I now use a pageless A4 size in Portrait mode with 0.2 margins.

Comment: You can make "Pageless" your default, with 0.2 margins. Then you do not need to care about it any more. Doing this now since the Q/A here, and it is the best, together with Code Blocks that allows you to get wide windows going over the border of the sheet for console output.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to File --> Page Setup --> Margins (inches).

Default is 1, I changed it to 0.2, up to you.

[image]

[image]

Live, 0.2 looks like:

[image]

And 0.5 like:

[image]

*Side-note: this code was formatted with the Code Blocks Add-on.*